# How to use multiple PN532 over i2c bus(es) and SPI?

Tags: programming, c++, esp32, i2c, communication

I am working on a project that involves 3 [PN532_module](https://www.elechouse.com/product/pn532-nfc-rfid-module-purple-version/)s to an ESP32, which sends the Tag_ID over BLE.
Plan A was to use One module on i2c_1, second on I2C_2 and third over SPI.

The SPI one works as expected.
Though I am having issues with using 2 I2c Buses using the same Adafruit Library. Exact issues are-

- Unreliable reading while using 2 different i2c buses
- Sometimes the SPI bus freezes after scanning a Tag on one of i2c connected readers.
  My code is here

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <Wire.h>
//#include <Adafruit_PN532_2.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>


#define SDA_1 (21)
#define SCL_1 (22)  
#define SDA_2   (33)
#define SCL_2   (32)  

Adafruit_PN531 nfc1(SDA_1, SCL_1);
Adafruit_PN532 nfc2(SDA_2, SCL_2);


void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) delay(10); 
Serial.println("Serial ready");

  nfc1.begin();
  nfc2.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata_1 = nfc1.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata_1) {
    while (1); // halt
  }
Serial.println(versiondata_1);

  uint32_t versiondata_2 = nfc2.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata_2) {
    while (1); // halt
  }
Serial.println(versiondata_2);
}


void loop(void) {

  uint8_t success_1;
  uint8_t uid_1[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength_1;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes 

  uint8_t success_2;
  uint8_t uid_2[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength_2;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes



  success_1 = nfc1.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid_1, &uidLength_1);
  delay(10);
  
  success_2 = nfc2.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid_2, &uidLength_2);
  delay(10);



  if (success_1) 
  {
    Serial.println(success_1);
    Serial.print(" UID_1 Value: ");
    nfc1.PrintHex(uid_1, uidLength_1);
    Serial.println("");
  }
  delay(10);


  if (success_2) 
  {
    Serial.print(" UID_2 Value: ");
    nfc2.PrintHex(uid_2, uidLength_2);
    Serial.println("");
  }
  delay(10);


}
```

Comment: Why not simply use SPI for all 3 instances of this chip ? You need the 3 basic shared SPI bus pins  SCK, MISO and MOSI. Each chip needs additionally one dedicated CS (Chip Select) pin. See https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/breakout-wiring (where this pin is called SSEL) and anyway you have said already that SPI works for you.

Comment: Both I2C and SPI is a bus architecture, meaning that multiple devices can share the same bus without needing separate wiring for each device as long as they have different address (in case of I2C) or have separate chip select (in case of SPI). All three can share the same I2C bus or SPI bus. Read [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I²C) and [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) for more details.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for answering, For I have discovered, they have FIxed i2c Address, so having them all on the same Bus isn't possible.  Also having 2 Different buses also doesn't quite solves the problem. As the problem is the Library having only one class for all 3 Interfaces(SPI, i2c and HSU). 
- Regards

Comment: As mentioned by 6v6gt, you could use the SPI with 3 wires sharing among all three devices for MOSI, MISO and SCK, with another 3 GPIO pins configured as CS for each of the board. Class is a footprint (library), you don't use the Class directly, you create an instance of the Class for each board.